# independent set in polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $P^n$ be polynomial vector space with real coefficients and with degree $≤n∈N$. Show that the set $ \{t_0, t-t_0,(t-t_0)^2,...,(t-t_0)^n \}$ is independent in $P^n$, where $t_0$ is arbitrary given real number that is not zero.

We learned in previous lectures that the set $\{1, x, x^2,...,x^n\}$ is independent in $P^n$ so I tried to substitute $t-t_0$ with $x$. Then I got $\{t_0, x, x^2,...,x^n\}$, but I think that would be true only if $t_0$ was $1$, so now I'm stuck.

Comment: All that matters is that $t_0$ is constant, not what constant value it takes

Comment: @user365239 Okay but how can I prove that? Is it correct if I substitute the first set so I'd get $\{t_0, x, x^2,...,x^n\}$? Then, from $α_0t_0 + α_1x + α_2x^2 + ... + α_nx^n = 0$ I could prove that $α_0=α_1=α_2=...=α_n$, which means the set is independent. Is that a good proof?

Comment: @user365239 Does that mean that $x$ in $\{t_0, x, x^2,...,x^n\}$ can be any kind of 1st degree polynomial and the proof for independency would still hold? If the first set was, for example, $\{3, t+2, (t+2)^2,...,(t+2)^n\}$, does that mean I could still substitute $t+2$ with $x$ and prove the independency as I did in the comment above?